# SharePoint Designer 2010 access on SiteCollection level?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have multiple SiteCollections in my SharePoint 2010 Farm and want to allow the SharePoint Designer access individually.
Only SiteCollection Admins which I authorize to use the SharePoint Designer should use it.
I have not found any way to manage the ShrePoint Designer access at SiteCollection level for SiteCollection Administrators.

Any ideas? :-(

(Please not by Group Policy)

Comment: can i ask why not group policy? that dosent make sense... actually you cant deny a sitecollection admin any permissions on the site collection he administrate...

Comment: Hey Leonardo, because we have a few self-administrated computers in our domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.  You can change the settings for SharePoint Designer usage in the SharePoint Designer Settings page (/_layouts/SharePointDesignerSettings.aspx) but that is not user specific.  I think the reason is that Microsoft's concept of Site Collection Administrator is that they are all the same.

If there are certain users that you want to have Full Control but not SharePoint Designer usage, I recommend adding them to an admin group and giving them Full Control on your site.  It's certainly not the same as being a Site Collection Administrator but I don't think there is a way to achieve what you want.